# Eclipse Juno cannot make new project after update

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-juno

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, and to install Eclipse Juno I downloaded it from the official site (I don't use apt-get nor software center)

After updating it from help > check for updates menu, my Eclipse cannot make new project. When I hover File > New, there isn't any menu to select (as the usual Java Project, C++ Project etc.), only an unselectable text like this:

> < No Applicable Items >

Anyone know what causes this?

Comment: If all of your Perspectives are closed, Open a Perspective.  Otherwise, which Juno did you download?  What was the actual filename?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

nitind's answer above helped solve my problem. I was using eclipse java ide juno on windows and i could not see any items under File -> New or under Window -> Show View. I noticed eclipse had defaulted to using the Java-EE perspective. Following nitind's suggestion I changed it to the Java perspective and can now see all the menu items. thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error when i first started the program, but i looked into it, and I saw that the workspace already had .cpp and compiled files in it which i had compiled earlier with a different program. To fix the error, I just changed the workspace to the default, and it worked fine.

I was using eclipse CDT Kepler with java 1.6.0_27. I then tried it with java 1.7.0_25 and eclipse Juno and this method resolved the error in any of these instances.

Try using the default workspace and it should work.

Regards, 
Nikita